# Using multiple columns in a dataframe to incrementally tag data

Tags: r

Below is some sample data. I am looking to make the column Segment_ID. Conceptually, I think I need code that does this:
For each SiteID, run through the timeseries and where there is Decay or Growth in the Decay column and a Y in the Valid column, mark this with a segment_ID number until one of these values changes. Then mark it as NA or a new segment_ID depending on the new combination of variables.
Changing the SiteID, the decay value or the valid value can trigger a change to the next incremental segment_ID or to NA.
What function or package can I use for this, on a large dataset?

```
df=data.frame(SiteID=c(rep("A",12),rep("B",12),rep("C",12)),
      date=c(rep(c("1/06/2021 9:05",    "1/06/2021 9:10",   "1/06/2021 9:15",   "1/06/2021 9:20",   "1/06/2021 9:25",    "1/06/2021 9:30",
              "1/06/2021 9:35", "1/06/2021 9:40",   "1/06/2021 9:45",   "1/06/2021 9:50",   "1/06/2021 9:55","1/06/2021 10:00"),3)),
      reading   = rnorm(36, mean=440, sd= 30),
      Decay = c(rep("Decay",5), NA, NA, rep("Growth",4),NA, NA, rep("Growth",5),rep("Decay",5),NA,rep("Decay",4),rep(NA,4), rep("Decay",4)),
      Valid=c(rep("Y",3),   "N","N",    NA, NA, rep("Y",8),"N",rep("Y",7),"N",rep("Y",4),   NA, NA, rep("Y",4), "N","N"),
      Segment_ID=c(rep(1,3),rep(NA,4),  rep(2,4),   rep(NA,2),rep(3,2), NA, 4   ,4, rep(5,5),   NA, rep(6,4),rep(NA,4), 7,  7,  NA, NA))
```

Comment: Plesase provide your expected output based on your input.

Comment: Hi Limey, thanks for engaging. The expected output is the column in the dataframe called Segment_ID. It's the final column in the code I've provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there may be various approaches to this - here is one using `tidyverse` and `rleid` from `data.table`.

First, you can use `rleid` to assign unique number IDs based on changes in `Decay` and `Valid`. Then, you can `filter` out rows that have missing `Decay` or "N" for `Valid`. Then, if to get consecutive IDs without skipping ID numbers, you can use `rleid` again. This will take IDs such as 1, 3, 6, 8, etc. and renumber as 1, 2, 3, 4...

Finally, you can `right_join` back to your original data, such that rows having missing `Decay` or "N" for `Valid` will be included again, but with `NA` as the ID to match your desired result. After that, I included `arrange` to order by `date` and for comparison with your desired output.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

df$date <- as.POSIXct(df$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

df %>%
  mutate(Segment_ID2 = rleid(Decay, Valid)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Decay) & Valid == "Y") %>%
  mutate(Segment_ID2 = rleid(Segment_ID2)) %>%
  right_join(df) %>%
  arrange(SiteID, date)
```

**Output**

```
   SiteID                date  reading  Decay Valid Segment_ID Segment_ID2
1       A 2021-01-06 09:05:00 418.6572  Decay     Y          1           1
2       A 2021-01-06 09:10:00 438.1956  Decay     Y          1           1
3       A 2021-01-06 09:15:00 437.6165  Decay     Y          1           1
4       A 2021-01-06 09:20:00 392.4035  Decay     N         NA          NA
5       A 2021-01-06 09:25:00 461.9040  Decay     N         NA          NA
6       A 2021-01-06 09:30:00 476.9435   <NA>  <NA>         NA          NA
7       A 2021-01-06 09:35:00 449.6172   <NA>  <NA>         NA          NA
8       A 2021-01-06 09:40:00 475.5905 Growth     Y          2           2
9       A 2021-01-06 09:45:00 410.9724 Growth     Y          2           2
10      A 2021-01-06 09:50:00 412.8886 Growth     Y          2           2
11      A 2021-01-06 09:55:00 419.8802 Growth     Y          2           2
12      A 2021-01-06 10:00:00 485.1212   <NA>     Y         NA          NA
13      B 2021-01-06 09:05:00 465.1645   <NA>     Y         NA          NA
14      B 2021-01-06 09:10:00 426.0098 Growth     Y          3           3
15      B 2021-01-06 09:15:00 432.8638 Growth     Y          3           3
16      B 2021-01-06 09:20:00 438.9166 Growth     N         NA          NA
17      B 2021-01-06 09:25:00 400.4518 Growth     Y          4           4
18      B 2021-01-06 09:30:00 481.7279 Growth     Y          4           4
19      B 2021-01-06 09:35:00 482.1005  Decay     Y          5           5
20      B 2021-01-06 09:40:00 456.7946  Decay     Y          5           5
21      B 2021-01-06 09:45:00 451.7381  Decay     Y          5           5
22      B 2021-01-06 09:50:00 442.5843  Decay     Y          5           5
23      B 2021-01-06 09:55:00 439.3795  Decay     Y          5           5
24      B 2021-01-06 10:00:00 390.8042   <NA>     N         NA          NA
25      C 2021-01-06 09:05:00 418.7951  Decay     Y          6           6
26      C 2021-01-06 09:10:00 433.7840  Decay     Y          6           6
27      C 2021-01-06 09:15:00 429.2208  Decay     Y          6           6
28      C 2021-01-06 09:20:00 470.7221  Decay     Y          6           6
29      C 2021-01-06 09:25:00 408.3244   <NA>  <NA>         NA          NA
30      C 2021-01-06 09:30:00 427.6083   <NA>  <NA>         NA          NA
31      C 2021-01-06 09:35:00 412.6484   <NA>     Y         NA          NA
32      C 2021-01-06 09:40:00 418.1401   <NA>     Y         NA          NA
33      C 2021-01-06 09:45:00 471.5464  Decay     Y          7           7
34      C 2021-01-06 09:50:00 453.2432  Decay     Y          7           7
35      C 2021-01-06 09:55:00 403.3955  Decay     N         NA          NA
36      C 2021-01-06 10:00:00 459.6489  Decay     N         NA          NA
```

Comment: rleid is my new favourite function - thank you!